# C++ DLL function used in Delphi7

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, dll, type-conversion

I want to use c++ DLL in my delphi 7 project.I have successfully call one function of DLL in my delphi7 project but getting error in another function in which parameter is stringbuilder. 
C++ function detail is as follow.(which i got from header file of dll)

```
WN_COMM_ERR WINAPI MYFUNCTION(WN_COMM_HANDLE handle, const char *command, char *answer, unsigned long maxlen, unsigned long timeout_ms, WN_ANSWER_TYPE *type);
```

And Answer type is enum type :-

```
 typedef enum {
    WN_ANSWER_ACK = '>',        // An OK frame was received
    WN_ANSWER_NACK = '!',       // An ERR frame was received
    WN_ANSWER_TOUT = 0,         // Command timed out before an answer could be received
}WN_ANSWER_TYPE;
```

I have successfully call same function in c# code and it is working.But I have no idea how to call it on delphi7 because answer parameter is stringbuilder type and in delphi7  their is not any stringbuilder type thing. I have tried to use Pansichar,string,pchar but not getting value in answer type variable :-

### C# declaration :Working

```
    [DllImport("wn_comm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern UInt32 MYFUNCTION(IntPtr handle, string command, StringBuilder answer, UInt32 maxlen, UInt32 timeout_ms, ref Int32 answer_type);
```

### Calling C# function : Working

```
WriteNowWrapper.MYFUNCTION(this.comm_handle, command, sbAnswer, (uint)sbAnswer.Capacity, Timeout, ref answerType)
```

When i called  above from my c# application i have successfully receive answertype and sbanswer variable values.

### Delphi7 declaration :Not Working

```
function MYFUNCTION  (handle:Longint; command:string;var answer:PAnsichar; maxlen:integer; Timeout:integer; VAR answretype:INTEGER) : longint; stdcall; external 'wn_comm.dll';
```

### Delphi7 calling function:Not Working

```
   MYFUNCTION(self.comm_Handle,command,answer,2,Timeout,answerType)
```

when I called MYFUNCTION  from delphi7 application. It executed successfully and update value in answertype which is integer type parameter but in answer variable i am getting blank.

Can anyone help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html and http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html

Answer (score 1):

Your Delphi function is declared incorrectly. You must not use `string` which is a native Delphi type. And the answer argument is not a var parameter.

The declaration should be:

```
function MYFUNCTION(
    handle: Integer; 
    command: PAnsichar;
    answer: PAnsichar; 
    maxlen: Cardinal; 
    timeout_ms: Cardinal; 
    out answer_type: Integer
): Cardinal; stdcall; external 'wn_comm.dll';
```

The missing detail in your question is the part where `answer` is allocated. You clearly do that in the C# code. That will look something like this:

```
StringBuilder sbAnswer = new StringBuilder(256);
```

I've guessed at what value to use for the capacity. In your Delphi calling code you need something similar.

```
var
  handle: Integer; 
  command: AnsiString;
  answer: AnsiString;    
  timeout_ms: Integer; 
  answer_type: Integer;
  err: Integer;
....
handle := ...;
command := ...;
SetLength(answer, 256);
timeout_ms := ...;
err := MYFUNCTION(
    handle, 
    PAnsiChar(command), 
    PAnsiChar(answer), 
    Length(answer),
    timeout_ms,
    answer_type
);
```

Comment: Would the voter care to explain, or is this just blind revenge?

Answer (score 0):

I think your function needs to be in the form :

```
function MYFUNCTION(
    handle: Integer; 
    command: PAnsichar;
    answer: PAnsichar; 
    maxlen: Cardinal; 
    timeout: Cardinal; 
    out answer_type: Integer
): Cardinal; stdcall; external 'wn_comm.dll';
```

Most of C++ functions will be cdecl so you can try **cdecl** instead of **stdcall**  .

Answer (score -1):

Type 
Without having access to the DLL it's har to say what is wrong. But try this for a start

```
function WN_ExeCommandA  (handle:Longint; command: PAnsichar;var answer:PAnsichar; maxlen:integer; Timeout:integer; VAR answretype:INTEGER) : longint; stdcall; external 'wn_comm.dll';
```

If I could see the c++ definiton of WN_ANSWER_TYPE  I could help you more.

Comment: it just a enum typedef enum {
 WN_ANSWER_ACK = '>',  // An OK frame was received
 WN_ANSWER_NACK = '!',  // An ERR frame was received
 WN_ANSWER_TOUT = 0,   // Command timed out before an answer could be received
}WN_ANSWER_TYPE;

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Then what is right? Can you explain what type of data type i should use for this.

Comment: @Pri I explained it in my answer

Comment: @PriyankaMehta: The `var` is wrong. It is simply `answer: PAnsiChar`. `PAnsiChar` is already a pointer (`char *`). Using `var` would add one level of indirection to that, and that would be wrong. I already posted it, but again: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html#params .